# Nested Python Packages/Django Application Packaging

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-apps, python-packaging

I have a library that I am creating for use across multiple applications. It consists of a set of abstract base classes that are in the "main" package, and a series of reusable Django applications.

Files in mylib-core:

- mylib/__init__.py
- mylib/models.py
- mylib/serializers.py
- mylib/viewsets.py

Files in mylib-auth:

- mylib/auth/__init__.py
- mylib/auth/models.py
- mylib/auth/serializers.py
- mylib/auth/viewsets.py

These are two libraries that are to be packaged separately, where `mylib-auth` depends on `mylib-core` and the classes in `mylib-auth` are derived from those in `mylib-core`

The issue that I am having is that when running the test runner for `mylib-auth` the files for `mylib-core` are not found. I have installed the the `mylib-core` package into the virtualenv for `mylib-auth`.

I think this has to do with my nested package structure - where I have a `mylib` folder in both packages. It seems python is only looking for files in the parent `mylib` directory that contains the `auth` subfolder and is ignoring the files in the `venv/lib/.../mylib` directory.

This results in the following errors:

When I attempt to run my test suite for `mylib-auth` I get an error that the application `mylib.auth` cannot be found because `mylib` has no property `auth` - despite having installed the `mylib-core` into my virtualenv. Adding a `__init__.py` under the `mylib` directory in the auth package fixes this (but obviously shouldn't be there, as this file is defined in my core package).  After this I get `ImportError: No module named 'mylib....'` errors.

What is the appropriate way to test and deploy nested packages?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the documentation: [pkgutil-style namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkgutil-style-namespace-packages)

Both packages must have the `mylib/__init__.py` file and with the following contents:

```
__path__ = __import__('pkgutil').extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

And everything works as expected.